# jQuery refactoring, how to make simple short code for this

Tags: javascript, jquery

They are different selectors and functions.
But they are very similar.

Is there any way to make it simpler?

```
var detailBtn = $('.doc__footer__menu__detail');
var detailModal = $('.doc__footer__detail');
var detailClose = $('.doc__footer__detail-close');

var activateDetail = function() {
    detailBtn.addClass('active');
    detailModal.addClass('active');
    detailClose.addClass('active');
    $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
    $('html').addClass('lock-scroll');
    return false;
}

var deactivateDetail = function() {
    detailBtn.removeClass('active');
    detailModal.removeClass('active');
    detailClose.removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
    $('html').removeClass('lock-scroll');
}

//
var relBtn = $('.doc__footer__menu__rel');
var relModal = $('.doc__footer__rel');
var relClose = $('.doc__footer__rel-close');

var activateRel =function() {
    relBtn.addClass('active');
    relModal.addClass('active');
    relClose.addClass('active');
    $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
    $('html').addClass('lock-scroll');
    return false;
}

var deactivateRel = function() {
    relBtn.removeClass('active');
    relModal.removeClass('active');
    relClose.removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
    $('html').removeClass('lock-scroll');
}

//
var attachBtn = $('.doc__footer__menu__attachment');
var attachModal = $('.doc__footer__attachment');
var attachClose = $('.doc__footer__attachment-close');

var activateAttach =function() {
    attachBtn.addClass('active');
    attachModal.addClass('active');
    attachClose.addClass('active');
    $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
    $('html').addClass('lock-scroll');
    return false;
}

var deactivateAttach = function() {
    attachBtn.removeClass('active');
    attachModal.removeClass('active');
    attachClose.removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
    $('html').removeClass('lock-scroll');
}
```

They are almost the same code except for the words 'detail', 'rel', 'attach'.

Stackoverflow said it looks like my post is mostly code, so I have to add some more details, but I don't know what should I say more XD

I imagine that if I use loop that 3 words as array, can it be possible?

Comment: Stackoverflow's [help] and [ask] should also hint that codereview is not a good fit for SO

Comment: You are likely looking for toggleClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try toggleClass

```js
const toggle = function(what, on) {
  $(".doc__footer__menu__" + what)     .toggleClass('active', on);
  $(".doc__footer__" + what)           .toggleClass('active', on);
  $(".doc__footer__" + what + "-close").toggleClass('active', on);
  $('body').toggleClass('lock-scroll', on);
  $('html').toggleClass('lock-scroll', on);
}
```

using

```
toggle('detail',true);
toggle('rel',true);
```

to turn on

and

```
toggle('detail',false);
toggle('rel',false);
```

to turn off

Answer (score 1):

If you can send a parameter when you call the function then you can do something like this:

```
var activateDetail = function(rule) {
  $('.doc__footer__menu__' + rule).addClass('active');
  $('.doc__footer__' + rule).addClass('active');
  $('.doc__footer__' + rule + '-close').addClass('active');
  $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
  $('html').addClass('lock-scroll');
  return false;
}

var deactivateDetail = function(rule) {
  $('.doc__footer__menu__' + rule).removeClass('active');
  $('.doc__footer__' + rule).removeClass('active');
  $('.doc__footer__' + rule + '-close').removeClass('active');
  $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
  $('html').removeClass('lock-scroll');
}

activateDetail('detail');
activateDetail('rel');
activateDetail('attachment');
```

Comment: The next step would be to pass in active (true/false) and use `.toggleClass("active", active)`  (`.toggleClass(className, state)`) so you only have one function.

Comment: @freedomn-m good point, I thought about making it better, but i stopped because I also wanted the OP to understand it.

Comment: @freedomn-m Like mine ;)

Comment: @Pete Where does it state that it's only a js question

Comment: @Pete I didn't say it was, I'm just trying to understand you, the OP is using jquery and has tagged it with jQuery, so why would it be a js question only?

Comment: Hence upvote + "next step".  I had a half-written answer, but didn't see the need to have two very similar (@mplungjan ... though probably similar, given the times).

Comment: I used jQuery because OP did. Also I mentioned toggleClass in a comment on the question a few minutes before I wrote the answer

Comment: @freedomn-m I agree, I don't mind a downvote if people would be man enough to explain why we all want to learn from our mistakes.

Comment: @Pete my apologies.  I've removed my nefarious comment.

Comment: @Pete it's also one of the reasons we so many valid answers as comments (myself included).  If someone doesn't like a question, they frequently downvote answers for having the audacity to try to help someone.